# Samsung wifi printer printing garbage after upgrading to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, printing

After upgrading to Ubuntu my Samsung wifi Multifunction printer prints random characters regardless of the version of the suldr driver.

Answer (score 1):

That was happening to me when I was printing to my Samsung M2820-DW because linux was sending the print job driverless, but in raw mode.  I'm not an expert, but the following worked for me, both in Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04:

1. Open Ubuntu Settings.
2. Choose Printers from the left panel
3. Up near the top right of the main window, click the `Add` button
4. Your printer should show up in a list with and address of {bunch of hex digits}.local .  Select that, and click the `Add` button in that window.
5. The system may offer to download a driver.  If so, accept it.

That's it.  To check your work, point your browser at localhost:631 , and choose the `Printers` tab.  The printer you added should show up as having a model something of the form, "Samsung M262x series, driverless, cups-filters 1.20.2"  Print to that one.  Do NOT print to the printer that has a model, "Local Raw Printer," even though it appears to be your Samsung.  The latter is the one that prints reams of random characters.

Answer (score 0):

First install the suldr driver either by downloading it from the HP/samsung site, or via the https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr repository (see https://github.com/dorfsmay/laptop-setup-ubuntu-18.04/blob/master/idempotent/031-suldr-samsung-drivers). This is required to be able to use the scanner.

Then:

- open a browser
- navigate to localhost:631
- click on "Printers" in top bar
- click on name of the printer (Samsung...)
- Click on the "Administration" drop down menu, and select "Modify Printer"
- You'll be prompted for your user id and password, enter your Linux login credentials
- select the first printer in "Discovered Network Printers", "Continue"
- "Continue" again
- select "Samsung XXXXX **driverless** cups-filters", "Modify Printer"

Now when you click again on "Printers" in the top bar, it should show "driverless" under "Make and Model"